# Dice roller - Python OOP

Tags: python, class, oop, dice

I need to make a program where the user should be able to define

1. How many sides are on the dice
2. How many times the dice is rolled
3. How many dice there are

I'm trying to build the basic structure. I have started with the properties `sides` and `rolled` which will be in my main class `Dice`. I'm assuming here that I will always have 1 dice. Then I created a subclass called `Dices`( trying to make it plural) which will inherit the `Dice` class members.

However, I'm trying to introduce a new property called `number_of_dice` which I haven't set up in my main class, and it will take more than 1 dice. When I try to print `print(input_more_dice.number_dice())` I get the following error:

```
  in __init__
    self.number_of_dice = number_of_dice
NameError: name 'number_of_dice' is not defined
```

I'm sure I'm not setting this up correctly. Here is my **(Updated)** code:

```python
import random 

# One dice result 
class Dice:
    sides = 0
    rolled = 0

    def __init__(self, sides, rolled):
        self.sides = sides
        self.rolled = rolled
        

    def rolling_output(self):
        

        if self.rolled == 1:
            rolled_once = random.randint(0, self.sides)
            return rolled_once
        else:
            list_of_results = [];
            for i in range(self.rolled):
                rolled_more = random.randint(0,self.sides)  
                list_of_results.append(rolled_more)

            return list_of_results  

# More than one Dice         
class Dices(Dice):
    number_of_dice = 0

    def __init__(self, number_of_dice):
        self.number_of_dice = number_of_dice

        super().__init__(sides= self.sides, rolled= self.rolled, number_of_dice= self.number_of_dice)

    def number_dice(self):
        return self.number_of_dice


# input_one_dice = Dice(3, 3)
# print(input_one_dice.rolling_output())    

input_more_dice = Dices(number_of_dice= 2)
print(input_more_dice.number_dice())
```

Why is my subclass not accepting a new property?

Comment: Is the subclass a must have? If not I would recommend you using only one class.

Comment: The error I get from that is `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'number_of_dice'` - `number_of_dice` **is** defined on the line where it's assigned as an instance attribute. That doesn't really make sense as a subclass, it's a _collection_ of `Dice` not itself a `Dice`. And I don't think any of your loops make sense, as they all return from the first iteration - shouldn't there be some _random_ behaviour here?

Comment: Subclasses are typically for "type of" relationships, which this relationship isn't. Also, "Dice" is the plural of "Die" - so "Dices" doesn't make sense as a word.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm just looping in there to see if I get the value I want when I print, they are just for testing. I'm checking the random behaviour right now, for that I was thinking of defining a new function called 'rolling_output'. I was creating Dices (I know,  bad english but I was trying to make it plural) to define the functions that would appeal to 'more than one' dice behaviour.

Comment: My point is the loops can be trivially factored out, instead of `for side in range(self.sides): return self.sides`, use... `return self.sides`. The only thing you gain is checking that it's an integer greater than zero, and there are much more readable and semantically appropriate ways to do that.

Comment: Hello @jonrsharpe thank you for your suggestion. That does makes sense if I just want to check the class is working (newbie here).

Answer (score 0):

The number of parameters in the "**init**" in Dice class is 2(excluding self). But you tried to call the class Dice in Dices using 3(excluding self) parameters. Is it because of That? I am not that much familiar with Object Oriented programming. Also return doesn't work very well under loops.